# Optimize query of sql server

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I want number of users present in a department.i have 9 department.

now i am using "while" loop to count no of users present in an department.

Can you please suggest how to count no of users present in an department.

Department table(Columns: Id and DeptName)
User Table(Columns: Id, Name, deptId)

Please help me

Thanks

[EDIT]

```
User table
----------
id         name           deptid
1           a              1
2           b              1
3           c              2
4           d             null
5           e              3
6           f              4
7           g              2
8           h              4
9           i              5
10          j              5
11          k              null

Department
----------

id    name 
1      x
2      x1
3      y
4      y1
5      z
6      z1

Result
------
count    depetname
9         all
2         x
2         x1
1         y
2         y1
2         z
0         z1
```

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see **[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed60/7)**

**EDIT**

you should be use **RIGHT JOIN**

```
select 'all', count(0) from users

union

SELECT department.name, COUNT(users.id) FROM users Right Outer JOIN department 
     ON users.deptId=department.id GROUP BY department.id
```

Comment: thanks but need to change my requirement.

now if any department does not have any user then that is not showing in the result but i want to show that department which 0 users.

Comment: so you can use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I would give a try like this : select Department.DeptName, count(distinct user.DeptId) from Departement left outer join user on user.deptid=Departement.id group by department.id.

Comment: last query:

i want to count to total users having departments.means total user details.

let dept a has 10 and dept b has 20 users and 5 users doesnt have any department then total will be 30 not 35

Comment: @user1926138 if you show some code in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ and create your schema & data, it's better for helping you.

Comment: sorry i don't know how to use that one.Let me update my question.Please check the question again inside edit